# Do power supplies exist for Godox speedlights?

Tags: off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, studio-lighting, godox, power-supply

I am using several Godox speedlights with my Nikon D500 for studio work. Is there a power supply that works with the flashes whether they are AA-powered or using a Godox VB18 li-ion battery?

Comment: Need more information.
The question you posted is very vague.
**Summarize the problem,
Provide details and any research, and
When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried**

Answer (score 1):

Speedlights are designed to be small, light, portable and that requires battery power.  There are no commercially available AC adapters for them so you can plug them into a wall outlet.

There is a li-ion rechargeable external battery pack you can use with the AA-powered "TT" speedlights, the Godox PB960 which can power two speedlights at once; and any number of conventional 8xAA-powered external battery packs for a single speedlight. But the "V" li-ion powered speedlights do not have an external battery pack port, and cannot be hooked up to it.

If you need Godox strobes in a studio setting to run off AC power while in use, then consider their manual AC-powered monolights (the Mk II, Mk III and MS series also have radio triggering built-in that allow for remote power and group control).  Or the TTL/HSS AD li-ion battery-powered Witstro strobes that also have an optional AC-adapter (AD400 and AD600 models).

Comment: Thank you so much for the great info detail. I will follow it up.   Cheers kk

Comment: @kundabungkid, you're welcome Consider [accepting the answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so you can up you own rep.

Comment: It might also be noted that Godex's Li-Ion internal batteries for their speedlights hold considerably more power than the 4 AA batteries they typical have replaced. It's almost like having a "power pack" inside the flash instead of on an external, belt mounted power pack. They're that much better.

Comment: @MichaelC, since OP was *already aware* of the VB18 li-ion pack, and finding its capacity insufficient, that didn't seem like something that needed to be stated. And I've seen folks grumble there's no external battery pack port on the V li-ion models, which would indicate OP's not the only one.

Comment: @inkista Perhaps. I've known a few folks who don't seem to be aware that the VB-18 is the Wh equivalent of about 7 Li-Ion AAA batteries and prefer to use the 4-AA versions with an 8-AA belt pack. Since the flash power is provided by the belt pack only and the 4 AA batteries inside the flash only power the logic circuitry, that's only a modest 12% or so difference between the VB18 and 8 Li-Ion AAs.

Comment: I'm not sure I read the OP saying they have *found* the VB18 to be insufficient. It could be that they *expect* an internal battery to be little or no improvement over AA batteries? As [this comment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129283/do-power-supplies-exist-for-godox-speedlights/129290?noredirect=1#comment249677_129283) points out, the question is more than a bit vague as to what the OP is looking for. Mains powered supply? External battery supply (due to a perhaps improper assumption that the VB18 is no better than 4 AAs)?